# Module Over the Group Algebra of a Ring

Tags: modules, representation-theory, group-rings

I'm aware that if $K$ is a field, $V$ a $K$-vector space, and $G$ is a group, then a $K$-representation of $G$ in $V$ is the same thing as a $KG$-module, where $KG$ is the group algebra of $G$ over $K$. I'm working on an exercise that asks how the situation changes when $K$ is any commutative ring. Would it be true then that a $KG$ module is still the same thing as a group homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Aut}_K(V,V)$? If so, is there a name for this structure? (I would guess something along the lines of a "module-representation of a group" but after a quick Google search it seems like this isn't a structure that's talked about.)

Comment: You may want to look at what are called $A$-categories, where $A$ is a ring. These are defined, for instance, in SGA 5.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking here. Based on the tag and title, it looks like you're familiar with the synonymous terms "group algebra" and "group ring," even though it sounds like you're asking "what is this object called?" And so there remains the question of whether there is an equivalence between $KG$-modules and $G$-representations over $K$—is that your question? If so, what have you tried, besides google?